# need to apply transformation on hive table column using spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where i have to extract the data from one column (hive table) and insert into other derived column. (Please find below config file data).

## table_column_name,search_text, replace_with, derived_column_name

Number, 1, DOWN, derived_column1
Number, 2, DEGRADED, derived_column1
Number, 3, NORMAL, derived_column1
Number, 4, LOW, derived_column12
Number, 0, MMEDIATE, derived_column2

I am using spark dataframe. With the given config file if i trying to generate the df.withcolumn (string of when conditions) dynamically. Is there a way where i can execute the dynamic generated code.
For example suppose i created below string using loop on the config file.

res1: String =  .withColumn("derived_column1",when(col("Number") === "1","DOWN").when(col("Number") === "2","DEGRADED").when(col("Number") === "3","NORMAL").when(col("Number") === "4","LOW").when(col("Number") === "0","IMMEDIATE").otherwise(col("Number")))

Now i would like to know is there a way where i can apply this withcolumn generated string to dataframe forexample.
**df.res1**

please let me know if it is possible or is there a better way of doing it.